# Hiding an element when "ImageBrush" image fails to load

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm using an OpacityMask with an ImageBrush, and would like to hide the element in cases where the image fails to load.  I tried using an EventTrigger, but this is

```
        <Rectangle x:Name="imageRoot"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
                    >
            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Uniform">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="ImageFailed">
                            <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Visibility"
                                                     TargetName="imageRoot">
                                <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                            </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </ImageBrush>
            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        </Rectangle>
```

This seems to just fail silently: there are no compile-time errors, nor runtime nor binding errors but the element does not collapse.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, "TargetName=imageRoot" is failing to bind the action to the element.  Using `TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=imageRoot}"` does work, however.